# Issue with creating a hosted zone in AWS for a transferred domain and linking to SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-ses

I recently transferred my domain from 1and1 to AWS Route53. I am now trying to link Amazon SES to the domain.

I went through the step of creating the hosted zone for the domain : my-domain.co.uk

Then I added all the necessary records for SES but for some reason it doesn't seem to find the records

IS there a way I can manually check if the records are there? I feel like something isn't quite right perhaps to do with the fact that the domain was taransferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not mention anything related to the `Nameserver` records creation, I am assuming you have not quite finished the transfer process

You can take a look at this doc [Transferring registration for a domain to Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53.html#domain-transfer-to-route-53-get-name-servers)

Above is a step by step process you can follow.

For SES you can follow this doc [Verifying domains in Amazon SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html)
 depending on the type of your setup, you can add necessary records and [Authenticating your email in Amazon SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-authentication.html) if needed.

Comment: It was to do with the Named Servers, thanks very much all sorted now.